# Expectile loss to reduce dependent variables overestimation

Tags: bias, quantile-regression

Say I have a a bunch of covariates $X$, and a dependent variable $y$, where $y$ is collected from people. However, I know from psychology that people will tend to overestimate $y$ given $X$ in some cases, cases that I definitely can discriminate using $X$ (say for example if $X$ contains the skin color of the person, and was collected in the 50')

Now, I would like to counterbalance this overestimation effect in my model, using the following loss:
$$
L = \sum w(x_i, y_i, f)(f(x_i)-y_i)^2
$$

where for example $w$ in its most basic form will be:
$$
w(x,y,f) = \begin{cases}
1  & \text{if $f(x)>y$,}\\
0.5 & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
$$

Thus using expectiles to counterbalance the overestimation... however, I'm not too sure that this will work / if it makes sense, any suggestion? Are there other methods to drive the model to prefer underestimation over overestimation?

Comment: Are you familiar with [quantile regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=quantile+regression+loss)?

Comment: @whuber yup, from there i discovered expectile regression, don't really know when someone would want to use one or the other, but it's probably something on the like of using MAE or MSE(?)

Comment: Well with one you model the quantiles of your target and with the other you model its expectiles. The question is what you need in your case. In any case, these different losses will not correct the effects of underestimation on your target distribution, rather they give you different ways to model this distribution.

Comment: @picky_porpoise _"these different losses will not correct the effects of underestimation on your target distribution"_ why not? I mean, would consider the 40% quantile as the 50% quantile, this should definitely "fix some overestimation"... but I'm definitely open to alternatives ahah

Comment: I see an argument in favor of explicitly estimating the $0.4$ quantile and calling it an estimate of the $0.5$ quantile (median), but knowing to estimate the $0.4$ quantile instead of $0.2$ or $0.48$ or $0.31$ implies that you already know something about by how much you have overestimated.

Comment: @Dave trust me, i’m definitely with you on that ahah but i can’t think of better ways than “good guessing”

Comment: @Alberto That's exactly my point. Your 'correction' results from interpreting one statistic as another one, not from changing the loss function.

Comment: @picky_porpoise oh ok sorry, didn't got it while reading it the first time...